# Bash Script - Check mounted devices

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, raspberry-pi

What I'm trying to do -
In the end, I want a script that checks for 3 devices, an SD card, Backup1 & Backup2. They've all been set to auto-mount at their respective mountpoints. The script should check for SD card first, if this fails, then a warning should be sent, and nothing more. If SD is okay, but only one backup is mounted, then ask for confirmation to go ahead with rsync to mounted backup. If all devices are mounted, then rsync from SD card to both backups.

Currently I'm just trying to get the device check nailed, using echo commands. Here's what I have (after multiple attempts) -

```
if ! mount | grep /media/card >/dev/null
then
    echo "ERROR: SD card not mounted, aborting"
else
    if ! mount | grep /media/backup >/dev/null
        then
            if ! mount | grep /media/backup2 >/dev/null
            then
                echo "ERROR: No backup devices"
            else
                echo "CAUTION: Backup_2 missing, Backup_1 OKAY"
            fi
    else
        if ! mount | grep /media/backup2 /dev/null
        then
            echo "CAUTION: Backup_1 missing, Backup_2 OKAY"
        else
            echo "SUCCESS: All devices OKAY"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Which isn't working. I'm getting confused by all the nested 'if's and surely there's a simpler way? Perhaps something that checks each device independently, then returns values that equate to the various combinations (0=no devices, 1=sd only, 2=sd & backup1, 3=sd & backup 2, 4 = all okay) which then is read and decides next part of script to run? If not, where has this way gone wrong?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Thanks, this is what was causing backup2 to think backup one was there when it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Part of the problem was using `mount | grep /media/backup > /dev/null` as there's an issue with similar names, so /media/backup2 being mounted meant it was counting both devices as mounted.

Using `grep -q /media/backup2\ /proc/mounts` works in a similar way, or at least produces the same outcome, just without the naming issue.

I've also changed the way the if statements work, it now checks for SD card, if that fails, then it aborts. It then checks for which devices are mounted with a fairly simple flow.

Here's the code:

GNU nano 2.2.6                                          File: backupSD2.sh                                                                                Modified

```
#!/bin/bash

#Check for SD

if ! grep -q /media/card\  /proc/mounts
then
    echo "ERROR: NO SD CARD"
    exit 0
else
    echo "SD OKAY..."
fi

#Check for Backup Devices

if (( grep -q /media/backup\  /proc/mounts ) && ( grep -q /media/backup2\  /proc/mounts ))
then
    echo "Both Backups mounted"

elif grep -q /media/backup\  /proc/mounts
then
    echo "CAUTION: Backup_2 missing, Backup_1 OKAY"

elif grep -q /media/backup2\  /proc/mounts
then
    echo "CAUTION: Backup_1 missing, Backup_2 OKAY"
else
    echo "ERROR: NO BACKUP DEVICES"
    exit 0
fi
```

After the 'echo' commands is where I'll be putting the rsync commands.
The final `exit 0` is probably unnecessary, but I don't think it's doing any harm and reassures that it's not going to try any more commands.

Comment: Care! Using `grep -q "$dev" /proc/mounts` will fail to found spaced mount points! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400577/1765658)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mountpoint`, which returns success (`0`) if the path is a mounted device, and `1` otherwise:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_mountpoint(){
if  mountpoint -q $1
  then
                printf "%s\n" "$1 is mounted"
                return 0
            else
                printf "%s\n" "$1 is not mounted"
                return 1
fi
}

check_mountpoint /media/sd 
if [ $? -gt 0 ]
  then
    printf "%s\n" "aborting"
    exit 0
fi
check_mountpoint /media/backup1
check_mountpoint /media/backup2
```

this is your code corrected, i hope it will help.

```
if mountpoint -q /media/sd
  then
    if mountpoint -q /media/backup
      then
        if mountpoint -q /media/backup2
          then
            echo "SUCCESS: All devices OKAY"
            # run your command here
          else
            echo "CAUTION: Backup_2 missing, Backup_1 OKAY, SD OKAY"
            # run your command here
        fi
      else
       if mountpoint -q /media/backup2
          then
            echo "CAUTION: Backup_1 missing, Backup_2 OKAY, SD OKAY"
            # run your command here
          else
            echo "SD OKAY , BACKUP Devices missing"
        fi
    fi
  else
    echo "SD is missing , Exit"
fi
```

Comment: Right! `mountpoint /media/card || die "/media/card not mounted"` will do the same!

Comment: This isn't saying anything about the backup drives, I've added the printf bit for them too, minues the && exit 0, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: you were right, i corrected the code and now it works.

Comment: Thank you, this works, how would I go about getting it to then rsync from SD card to whichever backup drives are attached?

Comment: my friend that's another question.

Comment: aha yeah, that's why I was trying to get this working with if statements, so it's easy to add in the rsync command under the corresponding one. I thought I had it working with a different setup, but it was just ignoring one if statement :(

Comment: i corrected your code , now it works .how about those 10 points? :D

Comment: Aha, thanks, I've got it working and posted an answer too, but I'll give you a tick (I'm trusting it works!)

Answer (score 1):

#### Check for 1 required mounted source AND at least 1 required mounted target

The best aproach for this is to build an ***array*** of mounted devices, then evaluate de count of elements in array.

#### Introduction

##### 1. Care! Using `grep -q "$dev" /proc/mounts` will fail to found *spaced* mount points!

```
/media/spaced target
```

in `/proc/mounts` will appear as

```
/media/spaced\040target
```

command `printf -v varname '%b' $varname` could help!

##### 2. Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) array and *associative array* to avoid fork

Instead of doing many fork to `grep`, (browsing same file many time), you could use bash for the job.

##### 3.  Parallelizing `rsync` on many targets

Using backgrounded jobs and `wait -n -p <VARNAME>`,  you could do `rsync` on many targets simultaneously.

##### 4. Using `/proc/self/mounts` instead of `/proc/mounts`

After having a look at `man 5 proc`.

#### Here is a script, within:

- you could configure as many backup targets you want.
- if all targets are mounted, script go on
- if no targets are mounted, script stop and
- if at least one target is mounted but not all, user is asked for *continuing*.

  - (this could be avoided by using `-y`/`-n` optional flag)
- On second part, all `rsync` are run as background job (parallelized),
- then script wait for all `rsync` to be done,

  - then print each result code with corresponding *target*,
- before finish

#### The script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source='/media/card'
backups=(
    /media/backup
    /media/backup2
    /media/other\ backup
)

die() {
    echo "$0[$$] ERROR: $@" >&2
    exit 1
}
warn() {
    echo "$0[$$] WARNING: $@" >&2
}
```

```bash
declare -A tobemounted="(['$source']='source')"
for target in "${backups[@]}";do
    tobemounted["$target"]=backup
done

mountedbk=()
while read -r _ mpnt _;do
    printf -v mpnt %b $mpnt
    if [[ -v tobemounted["$mpnt"] ]] ;then
        [[ ${tobemounted["$mpnt"]} == backup ]] && mountedbk+=("$mpnt")
        unset tobemounted["$mpnt"]
    fi
done </proc/self/mounts

[[ -v tobemounted["$source"] ]] && die "Source '$source' not mounted."

for missing in "${!tobemounted[@]}";do
    warn "Backup '$missing' not mounted."
done
(( ${#mountedbk[@]} == 0 )) && die "No backup present."

if (( ${#mountedbk[@]} < ${#backups[@]} ));then
    printf -v msg 'Only %d / %d backups targets are present.' \
        ${#mountedbk[@]} ${#backups[@]}
    warn "$msg"
    case $* in
        *-n* ) die Exit now. ;;
        *-y* ) warn Process anyway. ;;
        * ) read -rsn 1 -p 'Process anyway? (N/y): ' ans
            [[ "${ans//[yY]}" ]] && { echo No; die 'User abort.';}
            echo Yes ;;
    esac
fi
```

```bash
pids=() resultmsg=(success)
for target in "${mountedbk[@]}";do
    echo rsync "$source/." "$target/." &
    pids[$!]="$target"
done

while ((${#pids[@]}));do
    wait -np pid
    printf 'backup to "%s" end with %s.\n' \
        "${pids[pid]}"  "${resultmsg[$?]:-error}"
    unset 'pids[pid]'
done
```

Replace line:

```bash
    echo rsync "$source/." "$target/." &
```

by somethine like:

```bash
    rsync <your rsync options> "$source/SourcePath/." "$target/TargetPath/." &
```

#### Outputs could look like:

When source not ready:

```
$ ./backups.sh
./backups.sh[3721068] ERROR: Source '/media/card' not mounted.
```

When none of the targets are ready.

```
$ ./backups.sh
./backups.sh[3729071] WARNING: Backup '/media/backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3729071] WARNING: Backup '/media/backup2' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3729071] WARNING: Backup '/media/other backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3729071] ERROR: No backup present.
```

When some but not all targets are ready.

```
$ ./backups.sh
./backups.sh[3725569] WARNING: Backup '/media/backup2' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3725569] WARNING: Backup '/media/other backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3725569] WARNING: Only 1 / 3 backups targets are present.
Process anyway? (N/y): Yes
backup to "/media/backup" end with success.
```

```
$ ./backups.sh
./backups.sh[3729355] WARNING: Backup '/media/backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3729355] WARNING: Backup '/media/other backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3729355] WARNING: Only 1 / 3 backups targets are present.
Process anyway? (N/y): Yes
backup to "/media/backup2" end with success.
```

```
$ ./backups.sh 
./backups.sh[3854708] WARNING: Backup '/media/backup2' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3854708] WARNING: Backup '/media/other backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3854708] WARNING: Only 1 / 3 backups targets are present.
Process anyway? (N/y): No
./backups.sh[3854708] ERROR: User abort.
```

```
$ ./backups.sh -y
./backups.sh[3734321] WARNING: Backup '/media/backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3734321] WARNING: Backup '/media/other backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3734321] WARNING: Only 1 / 3 backups targets are present.
./backups.sh[3734321] Process anyway.
backup to "/media/backup2" end with success.
```

```
$ ./backups.sh -n
./backups.sh[3854855] WARNING: Backup '/media/backup2' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3854855] WARNING: Backup '/media/other backup' not mounted.
./backups.sh[3854855] WARNING: Only 1 / 3 backups targets are present.
./backups.sh[3854855] ERROR: Exit now.
```

When all targets are ready.

```
$ ./backups.sh
backup to "/media/backup" end with success.
backup to "/media/backup2" end with success.
backup to "/media/other\ backup" end with success.
```

Comment: Full rewrited answer, with complete script for parallelization.